# submit form and store data in database using tapestry

Tags: html, hibernate, tapestry, tml

I have been praticing tapestry for form submission and submitting data into database using hibernate.

I am referring below two links for it.

```
https://tapestry.apache.org/using-beaneditform-to-create-user-forms.html
https://tapestry.apache.org/using-tapestry-with-hibernate.html
```

But making form in these links is given using beaneditform component.

But I don't want  to use beaneditform and just make a normal html/tml submit form and store data to database. How can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Main reference page for Tapestry Forms & Validation can be found here: https://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html

Use `t:Form`, `t:TextField`, and other form components if you need finer control of your form elements & layout.

`BeanEditForm` is a helper component that allows quickly generate form for a given JavaBean. This component is just a mix of `t:Form` + `t:BeanEditor`.

You can also try one of the [Jumpstart](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/) examples, i.e.:

http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/input/forms1

explanations for the above example are here:

http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/input/formsexplained1